# Database access from another server

Tags: database

What format is the database stored?
Can the database be accessed from a website on another server?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

EE stores its data (by default) in a MySQL database using InnoDB type tables (earlier versions of EE used MyISAM type tables): MySQL or [Percona](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server) are listed [as requirements](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/installation/requirements.html) for the latest versions of EE, but it may work off other similar SQL type databases (e.g. [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/)).

Accordingly, as remote access operation is supported by MySQL, it is perfectly possible to run EE with data from a different database server (either co-located or remote), and / or to access EE's datatables directly from remote points.

HTH